# Only show featured image on exerpt and exclude images in post

Tags: posts, images, post-thumbnails

I have below code which displays the featured image from the post. But when I add an image to the post it also shows up with the featured image.

What I need to do is just show the featured image and some content from the post with a read more link, after someone clicks the read more link the other images should appear with the full post.

```
   <? query_posts('post_type=front&p=47');

    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

     <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

   <?   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
      the_post_thumbnail( 'front-thumb' );
    }    

    the_content('Read more');

    endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change `the_content('Read more');` to `the_excerpt();`

Then in your functions.php file

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'custom_read_more_link');
function custom_read_more_link($more) {
    return '<a href="'get_permalink().'">Read More</a>';
}
```

Also make sure that you're calling `wp_reset_query()` after the while loop. This will achieve what you're trying to do.

A personal suggestion: Please don't use `query_posts`, instead create a new instance of `WP_Query` class. It takes the same parameters as `query_posts` except that the code changes a little

```
$query = new WP_Query('post_type=front&p=47');

while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
```

The benefit of this is that you'll not modify the wordpress global `$wp_query` variable